# Visual Studio 2015 running executable much slower than command line

Tags: c++, git, visual-studio, dll

I have a rather large c++ project that consists of 3 DLLs and 1 executable.  The main executable dynamically loads the first DLL (loadLibrary).  This DLL is statically linked to the other 2 DLLs through the MSVS linker.  My team uses git for source control.  I have recently run into an issue where the Visual Studio debugger doesn't seem to be executing the main program correctly.  I have done some instrumenting and found that running in Visual Studio produces execution times ~12x slower than running the same exe and DLLs from the command line.

Diagnostic tools are disabled and I have built all 4 projects in Release mode.  I have even tried restarting my machine, clearing the cashe.  What is even more odd is that other team members are running the same code (same pull from git repository) and they are not seeing this.  All of our machines are configured the same.  Does anyone know what may be causing this?

Comment: Running any code with the debugger is going to result in a significant speed difference. Run your code without the debugger.

Comment: If you compile with optimization on but run under the IDE you should disable the debug heap. That's a separate setting in the IDE and slows things down a lot because `new` and `delete` invokes a stack corruption check. This doesn't happen running from the command line. OTOH, if you disable it you might not catch pointer bugs in your code.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear.  I know there will be some performance effects, but not this significant.  As I mentioned I have been running in VS for months prior to this.  The rest of my team is running in VS and not seeing this slowdown.

Comment: Since *"other team members are running the same code (same pull from git repository) and they are not seeing this"* most likely you messed up build process somehow or not actually running binaries that you think you are running.

Comment: Thanks Doug I will give that a try

Comment: Not magic. Time to sprinkle timers in your code and track it down. That's how I discovered VS was slowing down all my destructors that did heap deletes.

Comment: Well I set _NO_DEBUG_HEAP=1 and didn't see any improvement.  I have instrumented the code quite a bit.  I just don't understand why I am seeing this on my machine and others aren't.  All configurations are the same

Comment: Put timers in it. Something is different. Putting a high res timer around the destructor is how I found how slow things get with the debug heap using the exact same release code. I'm not sure when VS added the option in the IDE but that's the way to go with newer VS. I've never used _NO_DEBUG_HEAP as an environment variable (not a Macro Def) No idea how reliable that is with VS 2015.

Comment: You might also run procexp type tools to see exactly what dlls get invoked on systems that aren't slowing down and compare it with yours. Maybe the CRT stuff isn't the same.

Comment: Time to profile the code?